# Flutter keyboard resize problem on Real Phone

Tags: flutter, dart, resize, singlechildscrollview

my problem is exactly this; When the application I wrote with flutter works with the emulator, the body resizes when the keyboard is opened, but when I connect a real phone and try it, the keyboard hides the text fields.

Need to set a permission?

Comment: Can you please share the code?

Comment: Please add a code snippet of the widget that opens the keyboard. You should test your app in release mode over the physical device in order to check any error, maybe on your emulator the screen fits well and on your physical device it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

I got the similar problem inside scrollable widget, the solution is to wrap your widget with `Padding` like that:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final bottom = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;
  return SingleChildScrollView(
          controller: widget.controller,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: bottom),
            child: YourWidgetWithTextFields()
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it didn't work, then I tried deleting the <item name = "android: windowFullscreen"> true </item> part in styles.xml file in a different place.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to `false` in your Scaffold()

Like this:

```
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  body: // ...
  // ...
)
```

Documentation reference: [Scaffold - resizeToAvoidBottomInset](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/resizeToAvoidBottomInset.html)